# Something strange with if() in c

Tags: c, string, if-statement, struct

This is for a school project I'm working on, it's just a small part of the code but for some reason the program doesn't seem to go inside the if() no matter what the input is. I've tried anything and everything I know of (also used the isalpha() function) but it just won't run the commands inside the if().

```
do
{
    flag=1;
    gets(input.number);
    printf("\n%s\n",input.number);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(input.number);i++)
    {
        printf("yolo1\n");                                      //debug
        if(input.number[i]<48 || input.number[i]>57)            //PROBLEM HERE
        {
            printf("\nyolo2\n");                                //debug
            flag=-1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(strlen(input.number)<1000 || strlen(input.number)>9999 || flag==-1)  printf("\nINVALID INPUT\n\nARI8MOS: ");
}while(strlen(input.number)<1000 || strlen(input.number)>9999 || flag==-1);
```

Can you guys help me out here??? I've been staring and the code for the better part of 3 days now....

Comment: What type is `input.number`?

Comment: Maybe your compiler is trying to save you self-inflicted injury by treating `gets` as a nop instead of the stupidly dangerous function it was originally defined to be?

Comment: use `fgets()`...and are you sure about < 1000 or >9999 part?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `printf('%d', input.number[i])` to see what you're dealing with?

Comment: And please tell us exactly what test inputs you have tried. Also, best practice is not to use magic numbers like `48` and `57`. Instead use `'0'` and `'9'`. Finally, to check whether a string can be parsed as a valid number suggest using [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: Why not add code to print the value of `i` and the value of `input.number[i]` to see if it's what you expect?

Comment: Thank you a million sir Sourav Ghost!!! Having to answer to your question made me realize that I should have put <4 and >4 there and that proved to be the whole problem.....

Answer (score 2):

I presume you declared `char input.number[]`. 
Your condition in `if` says that you only want to get into its body if the character is NOT a digit. This is somehow contradictory to the name `input.number` of the variable (but perhaps you are just checking for incorrect characters here...)
To better see what is happening with the condition, you can choose to print the values of its components, like this:

```
printf("%c[%d]", input.number[i], input.number[i]); 

printf("%d, %d, %d\n", input.number[i]<48 , input.number[i]>57, input.number[i]<48 || input.number[i]>57);
```

(you will se a 0 for false and 1 for true)
BTW: You could write the same condition in a more readable manner, using char constants like this:
`input.number[i]<'0' || input.number[i]>'9')`

Comment: "This is somehow contradictory to the name input.number". The OP's intention is to validate that each character is a valid numeric digit. That condition checks for invalid characters and sets a flag to indicate invalid input.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your input but the answer proved to be a lot more simple (to the point of making feel stupid) than I expected. My error was that at the part that I check the length (<1000 >9999) the number are wait off target... It should be <4 and >4. Or in sort !=4